# Problema ao expirar sessão do Apache Shiro + vraptor-shiro

Tags: vraptor

Estou utilizando o [vraptor-shiro](https://github.com/dipold/vraptor-shiro) para integrar o [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) como mecanismo de segurança em um projeto meu e estou tendo um problema quando a sessão expira.

No método [onInvalidation](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/xref/org/apache/shiro/web/session/mgt/DefaultWebSessionManager.html#279) da classe [DefaultWebSessionManager](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/xref/org/apache/shiro/web/session/mgt/DefaultWebSessionManager.html) lança uma exceção porque o argumento passado é um [DefaultSessionKey](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/DefaultSessionKey.html) ao invés de uma [WebSessionKey](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/session/mgt/WebSessionKey.html) que parece ser o mais correto. Isso coloca a sessão do meu usuário em um estado inconsistente pois ele não consegue deslogar ou logar na aplicação.

Imagino que seja algum problema de configuração embora ainda não tenha encontrado exatamente o que, e estou a mais de uma semana com esse problema com outro colega de trabalho.

Eu consegui reproduzir o problema em um projeto [vraptor-blank-project e disponibilizei para quem quiser](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwT0xteZ_gXmTERINlFqaTNPdTg&authuser=0) dar uma olhada e talvez nos ajudar.

Valeu pessoal, até mais!

Comment: Olá, estava pesquisando e vi no seu código, esta funcionando, se você redireciona para alguma página se ele não esta logado ele retornar a mensagem, e vai em login, como já esta setado os dados ele loga, oque esta dando erro ?

Comment: Eu analisei o código com o vraptor-shiro e não da certo, algum conflito ou algo parecido. O unico jeito foi pegar o apache shiro e implementar no vraptor, e esta funcionando